# How to tag questions that is concentrated towards all sects except sect "A" and/or "B"?

Tags: discussion, tag, sect

It would be easy to mention in the question that, e.g.

> This question is intended for all sects *except* A, B and C.

But how can it be reflected in the tags?

More like [*regex-negation*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex-negation/info).

Answer (score 1):

The concept of tags and the way they form a taxonomy is not conducive to "negative" tags. You just can't do it without jury rigging the system and breaking other things.

Instead you should figure out what "positive" signals in a post need tagging. If sect does non play a major roll in forming the scope of a question, then it should be left off and something topical should be added instead. If on the other hand it is a significant signal, then the sects that are part of the question should be delineated.

If this doesn't work, then the fault likely lies with the question. Tags should always work as if they were connected by AND operators. A question tagged [x](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x), [y](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/y) should require somebody who is an export in BOTH X AND Y in order to properly answer. Somebody who is knowledgeable in X but knows nothing of Y should not be able to field the question.

If you have questions that call for an OR operator instead, the question is too broad and should be narrowed. This necessity will not always be met with open arms by those asking questions but it will foster a more constructive environment and more expert level question and answers.

Comment: Well, that's all clear, logical and correct. But what I intended to ask was that, OP wants answers that focus on any sect except A and B (for any reason), so is there way to reflect that in the tags?

Comment: @BleedingFingers I understood the question actually and I am familiar with OP's wanting some to ask questions like this. Usually this is because they don't know how to scope their question well enough but they do know of one sect they don't like. "*I want to know any opinions about X (however diverse) except I don't want anybody that believes Y to answer.*" This is simply not a constructive question pattern to encourage and the tagging system can actually serve as a warning sign that the question needs a more constructive scope.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Instead of trying to find a way to tag non constructive question patterns, the question should edited to be more constructive. The bad example from my previous comment should be fixed be asking the OP to focus on a sect that they DO want to hear from and editing to make it a specific question about them.

Comment: Well, no. That's not what I meant. e.g. *I know the above mention is not part of X so I'm interested about anyone except X which has it*. "anybody that believes" would be discriminatory.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Perhaps an example would help clarify.

Comment: This could be one: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10569/3487

Comment: @BleedingFingers The issue with that question seems to be that nobody has identified what it IS about yet. As soon as they to in will be much more apparent how to tag it. Sometimes only a domain expert well recognize and know what tags to use and the right person doesn't seem to have turned up yet. In the mean time the tag system is NOT for showing process of elimination (not this, no not thin either, etc). Just wait till somebody can pin down what/who/why for that question.

Comment: That answers the question. Please add it to the answer. Plus should the question be edited if it looks too generalized?